# Integral over a Funnel in Fermi coordinates

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we are in the Hyperbolic plane, defined as
$$
\{w = u + iv \mid v > 0\} \quad \text{with metric} \quad \frac{du^2 + dv^2}{v^2}\,.
$$
I am given a funnel $F$. This object is isometric to a half annulus
$$
A_F = \{ u \ge 0,\,1 \le u^2 + v^2 \le e^{2\ell_{\partial F}}\}
$$
with the edges $\{u^2 + v^2 = 1\}$ and $\{u^2 + v^2 = e^{2\ell_{\partial F}}\}$ identified, its boundary being totally geodesic of length $\ell_F$; in Fermi coordinates with respect to the geodesic boundary $\partial F$, the funnel is isometric to 
$$
\mathbb{R}^+_\delta \times (\mathbb{R} / \ell_{\partial F} \mathbb{Z})_\theta \quad \text{ with metric} \quad d \delta^2 + (\cosh \delta)^2 d\theta^2\,.
$$
I would like to determine the following integral
$$
\int_F \cosh \delta \,d\delta d\theta
$$
but unsure how to proceed. Can I write this as the limit
\begin{align*}
& \int_F \cosh \delta d\delta d\theta = \ell_{\partial F} \lim_{R \to \infty} \int^R_0 \cosh \delta d\delta = \ell_{\partial F} \lim_{R \to \infty}  [\sinh \delta]^R_0 = \ell_{\partial F} \lim_{R \to \infty}  \sinh R ?
\end{align*} 
The right hand is $\infty$, which is ok since the integral is going to be regularized in the end. What worries me is that I don't understand the boundary part $\ell_F$, this should depend on the coordinate $\delta$ so the above looks false to me.
Thanks a lot for your help!